# Serena Dimensions command line (dmcli) documentation

Tags: command-line-interface, pvcs, serena

Does any one has Serena Dimensions command line (dmcli) documentation PDF?

To get one from Serena website, I will need a serial number, and for that I will have to raise an organization level request. So it will be helpful if someone could provide me the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check dmcm_command-line_ref.pdf
https://sites.google.com/site/tecnosoftwareserena/dimensions/dmentrenamiento

Comment: This site can’t be reached.

Answer (score 2):

Just updating the answer. The link for all serena dimension related documentation can be found here:

http://help.serena.com/doc_center/doc_center.html#dcm

Entire Documentation portfolio is here:

http://help.serena.com/doc_center/cm/ver144/dmcm_all_docs_144.pdf

The way to reach to this to look for knowledge base links in the official serena website. Which will redirect to the current maintained database.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. dmcli reference is here: http://help.serena.com/doc_center/cm/ver144/dmcm_command_line_reference.pdf?zoom_highlight=dmcli#search=%22dmcli%22

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking on the 'help about' dialogue? Sometimes (depending on how the licenece was generated) there will be the serial number shown.
Anyone in the organisation should be allowed access to the support site.
I can send you a copy if need be.